# Graphics2d making a box

Tags: java, swing

I am new to java, I wanted to make a program that draws a box on screen, everything is correct except for the paintComponent(); which is not working

```java
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D.*;
public class Frame extends JPanel
{
    @Override //this section creates the box
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
     super.paintComponent(g);
     
     Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
     
     g2d.drawRect(150,150,20,20);
    
    }
    public static void createWindow() //this section creates the frame
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    //set closing bebavior
        frame.setSize(400, 400);                                 //set the size of jframe
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                       //center the jframe 
        frame.setVisible(true);                                  //show the frame
    }
    //main method  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        createWindow();//launch your creaWindow method  
        paintComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile. If that is what you meant by "not working", you should have said so, and shown the compilation error.

Comment: You never create an instance of the `Frame` class, so why would you expect the code to work?

Comment: You need to construct a `Frame` and add it to the `JFrame`:  `frame.add(new Frame());`

Answer (score 1):

You have to review the basics of Java. Your mistake in this is that you have to create an object of this class Frame and add it to the JFrame which you have created. Below is the correct code @Hh000.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D.*;
public class Frame extends JPanel{

    @Override //this section creates the box
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     g.drawRect(150,150,20,20);
    }
    
    //main method  
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  //set closing bebavior
        Frame frameObject = new Frame();                       //Making a class object
        frame.add(frameObject);                                //Adding the object into the JFrame
        frame.setSize(400, 400);                               //set the size of jframe
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                     //center the jframe 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```